# Set a moving v_line in a Shiny Application that does not start at 0

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following Shiny Application that allows you to filter a slice of a graph and lets you initiate a counter:

```
library(shiny)


UI <- fluidPage(

  div(style="display:inline-block",numericInput("start_time", "Starting time:", 1, min = 1, max = 100)),
  div(style="display:inline-block",numericInput("stop_time", "Stop time:", 5, min = 1, max = 100)),

  actionButton("start_counter","Start the counter"),

  plotOutput("plot_timeseries", width = "500px", height = "300px"),
  plotOutput("plot_timeseries2", width = "500px", height = "300px")

)


Server <- function(input, output, session) {

  counter <- reactiveVal(1)
  action <- reactiveVal(FALSE)

  # When goButton is clicked, set action() from FALSE to TRUE or the other way around.
  observeEvent(input$start_counter,
               {
                 action(!action())
               })

  # Add an oberserver that invalidates every second, and increments the counter if action()==TRUE
  observe({ invalidateLater(1000, session)
    isolate({
      if(action())
      {
        # Add 1 to our counter
        counter(counter() + 1) 
      }
    })
  })

  pp <- eventReactive(c(input$start_time, input$stop_time, counter()), {
    ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) +
      geom_point(size=2, shape=23) +
      scale_x_continuous(limits = c(input$start_time, input$stop_time)) +
      geom_vline(xintercept = counter())
  })

  output$plot_timeseries <- renderPlot({

    pp()  

  })

  output$plot_timeseries2 <- renderPlot({

    ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) +
      geom_point(size=2, shape=23) +
      geom_vline(xintercept =  counter())

  })

}


shinyApp(ui = UI, server = Server)
```

This works when I "slice" the graph from 1 to something. However I also want to be able to slice the graph from fe 3-6 and then have the v_line start at 3 seconds.

I tried to accomplish this by changing:

```
counter <- reactiveVal(1)
```

Into

```
counter <- reactiveVal(input$start_time)
```

This however gave me the following error:

```
Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do 
something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
```

Any thoughts on what I should do to achieve my objective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to achieve what you want. I modified your code only where it says `MODIFIED` or `ADDED`.

I have now set the vline to move to the start time whenever you press the reset button. You could also reset the line whenever the start_time changes, if that is your desired behavior. Simply change the `observeEvent` to:

```
  # ADDED - if start time changes, reset the counter.
  observeEvent(input$reset_counter,
               {
                 counter(input$start_time)
               })
```

Hope this helps!

---

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

UI <- fluidPage(

  div(style="display:inline-block",numericInput("start_time", "Starting time:", 1, min = 1, max = 100)),
  div(style="display:inline-block",numericInput("stop_time", "Stop time:", 5, min = 1, max = 100)),

  actionButton("start_counter","Start the counter"),
  actionButton("reset_counter","Reset the counter"), # ADDED


  plotOutput("plot_timeseries", width = "500px", height = "300px"),
  plotOutput("plot_timeseries2", width = "500px", height = "300px")

)


Server <- function(input, output, session) {

  counter <- reactiveVal(1)
  action <- reactiveVal(FALSE)

  # When goButton is clicked, set action() from FALSE to TRUE or the other way around.
  observeEvent(input$start_counter,
               {
                 action(!action())
               })

  # Add an oberserver that invalidates every second, and increments the counter if action()==TRUE
  observe({ invalidateLater(1000, session)
    isolate({
      if(action() & counter() < input$stop_time) # MODIFIED - stop at stop time.
      {
        # Add 1 to our counter
        counter(counter() + 1) 
      }
      else # ADDED - to stop the timer from running when we modify the start or stop time.
      {
        action(FALSE) 
      }
    })
  })

  # ADDED - if start time changes, reset the counter.
  observeEvent(input$reset_counter,
               {
                 counter(input$start_time)
               })

  pp <- eventReactive(c(input$start_time, input$stop_time, counter()), {
    ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) +
      geom_point(size=2, shape=23) +
      scale_x_continuous(limits = c(input$start_time, input$stop_time)) +
      geom_vline(xintercept = counter())
  })

  output$plot_timeseries <- renderPlot({

    pp()  

  })

  output$plot_timeseries2 <- renderPlot({

    ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) +
      geom_point(size=2, shape=23) +
      geom_vline(xintercept =  counter())

  })

}


shinyApp(ui = UI, server = Server)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you can only use `input$start_time` within a reactive context, that is `reactive()` or `observe()` or something like that.

The simplest way to do this is to just move your `counter(input$start_time)` into an `observe()` function like so:

```
observe({
    counter(input$start_time)
})
```

Unlike reactive expressions, observers use eager evaluation, which means that the re-execute right away when their dependencies change. What this means here is that this code block will run and update the value of `counter` right away before any of the `renderPlot` functions and it will run immediately whenever the value of `input$start_time` changes.